# Loading external .swf (projects) into a flex/flash builder application

Tags: flex3, flash, external, loading, flash-builder

I'm doing some research for a project that I might be doing soon, and I'd like to build it in Flex or Flash builder, but I just have a question.

I looking to build a sort of admin section of the application for users to sign and view personal data. The rest of the application would be split up into different sections or "modules" containing images, text, and quizzes that users could select to complete. Over time I would have about 20 modules.

I'm wondering if its possible to create the main application then have each module in its own .swf to load, so users would only be loading the module they would be using, also if a module ever need to be updated in the future I would only have to replace the module and not the entire application.

My thought is that each module would be built as separate projects in flex/flash builder, and then loaded with in the main application when called on.

Is this possible? any one have any resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=modular_5.html